# Difference between Sophie Germain primes are divisible by 3?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, conjectures

It seems that the difference between two Sophie Germain primes greater than 3 is divisible by 3. If this is true, how to prove it?

A Sophie Germain prime is a prime $p$ such that $2p+1$ also is a prime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A prime $>3$ is congruent to one of $\pm1\pmod6$. If $p\equiv1\pmod6$ then $2p+1\equiv3\pmod6$ is divisible by three and therefore $2p+1$ is not a prime.

So if $p$ is the smaller member of a Sophie Germain pair, we must have $p\equiv-1\pmod6$. Then $2p+1\equiv-1\pmod6$ as well, and the difference $p+1$ is divisible by six.

Comment: I think this answer a question different from the one asked. (Or, it is I that did this. :-))

Comment: Possibly, @quid :-). Luckily the answer to the other question is in there - at least implied.  On third reading it seems to me that I was the one misreading.

Comment: So, to make sure: this also implies that the difference between any two Sophie Germain primes $>3$, not necessarily in the same pair, is also a multiple of six. I initially misread the question to be about the difference $$(2p+1)-p=p+1,$$ but the same argument settles both versions.

Answer (score 13):

For $2p+1$ to be prime you need it to be not divisible by $3$. Thus $p$ must not be $1$ modulo $3$ and thus is $2$ modulo $3$ (except for $p=3$ which you excluded).

Thus every such $p$ is $2$ modulo $3$ and the difference of two such primes is divisible by $3$.

Comment: I find it interesting how patterns among the primes like this one are almost always either proven in a few sentences using machinery the ancient Greeks would understand, or it's basically unprovable as far as we currently know.

Comment: @A---B What I mean is that they didn't have access to Galois theory or elliptic curves or any of the other really fancy machinery that modern number theory does. And still, even with all of these modern techniques available, if a theorem about the primes admits a short and elegant proof, it usually admits a short and elegant proof using classical techniques.